# Cosmological evolution of a hyperbolic space form

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

Please consider the following metric

$$ ds^2 =-dt^2+f(t)( {\frac {a^2}{r^2+a^2}}dr^2+ r^2 d\Omega_{n-1})$$

where $d\Omega_{n-1}$ is the metric of the hyper-sphere $S^{n-1}$

Making "experimental symbolic computation" with the package GrTensor, I am obtaining that

$$f(t) = {\frac {1}{8}}{\frac {\left( 2\,{{\rm e}^{-2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\frac {\Lambda}{n \left( n-1 \right) }}}t}}-\frac{1}{2}\,n \left( n-1 \right)  \right) ^{2}{{\rm e}^{2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\frac {\Lambda}{n \left( n-1 \right) }}}
t}}
}{{\Lambda}^{\frac{3}{2}}{a}^{3}}}
  $$

is a solution for the Einstein equation with cosmological constant:

$$ G_{{\mu,\nu}}+\Lambda\,g_{{\mu,\nu}}=0 $$

My question is: how to derive this solution using only pen and paper?

Comment: In broad strokes: Compute the Christoffel symbols of the metric, then compute the curvature tensors, plug them into the Einstein equations, and derive + solve an ODE for $f(t)$.

Comment: I have a solution but it is only for a $3+1$ dimensional space instead of a $n+1$ dimensional space like you have. The best way would be to derive the Friedmann equation for more than 3 spatial dimensions. The density parameter form of the equations would make this easier to solve.

Comment: Leonard Hofstetter's joke : "I know a solution , but it only works for shperical chickens in a vacuum" :)

Comment: Joke:  Freud knows as much about general relativity as Einstein about psychoanalysis.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly a full solution, but too long for a comment.

It would be much easier to solve this using the Friedmann equation in density parameter form. In $3+1$ dimensional space we have

$$\frac{\dot{f}^2}{H_0^2f^2} = \frac{1-\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}{f^2}+\Omega_{0,\Lambda}$$

since in your equation the universe is devoid of everything except universal constant and curvature. This equation is separable - and taking the solution branch where the universe is growing, we obtain

$$H_0(t-t_0)+C = \int\frac{df}{\sqrt{1-\Omega_{0,\Lambda}+\Omega_{0,\Lambda}f^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}}\sinh^{-1}\left(f\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}{1-\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}}\right)$$

$$\implies f(t) = \sqrt{\frac{1-\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}{\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}}\sinh\left(H_0\sqrt{\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}(t-t_0)+\sinh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}{1-\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}}\right)\right)$$

or

$$f(t) = \cosh\Bigr(H_0\sqrt{\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}(t-t_0)\Bigr)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}}\sinh\Bigr(H_0\sqrt{\Omega_{0,\Lambda}}(t-t_0)\Bigr)$$

This solves the relationship in $3+1$ dimensions but you have an $n+1$ dimensional space. This would require determining the Friedmann equations in $n+1$ dimensional space. I conjecture that the equation for a universal constant and curvature only universe would not actually change in this setting since the dimensionality would only affect the $T_{\mu\nu}$ side of the equation which is $0$ here. But I am not entirely sure.

If my conjecture is correct, then this is the full solution.